# How can I fix my /testfor for if somebody has a nametag in their inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When I put into the command block:

```
/testfor @a[1219,4,547] {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:name_tag"}]}
```

and power it when I'm in the correct area, the comparator does not power. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Minecraft is this?

Comment: This command should power the comparator, could you screenshot your setup? You haven't specified a radius in the selector, which you probably want to do, but that'll just make it check everyone rather than making the command fail.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need testfor for this.  Just use /clear @a name_tag 0.  That will remove 0 name tags, giving a comparator output when a player has one.  You can replace @a with your area selector.